# ANTLR4 grammar, rule accept only part of the sentence

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4, context-free-grammar

all. I have created the grammar(it's part of the bigger grammar) to discover my problem

When I parse the string

> 00 */3,5 * * 5 America/New_York

I have following exception

> line 1:4 no viable alternative at input '/'

As I have discovered, problem is that substring */3,5 does fully parsed with "with_step_value" rule, instead of it parser get only first sybmbol. But why? As I understand, antlr try to parse as long string as he can and substring "*/3,5" in my poind of view satisfied to rule "with_step_value"

So, why it's happends and how to fix it?

Regards,
Vladimir

Please, see grammars and pictures bellow

```
/*File trigger validator lexer */
lexer grammar CronPartLexer;


INT_LIST: INTEGER (COMMA INTEGER)* ;
INTERVAL
:
    INTEGER DASH INTEGER
;

INTEGER
:
    [0-9]+
;

DASH
:
    '-'
;


SLASH
:
    '/'
;

COMMA
:
    ','
;

UNDERSCORE
:
    '_'
;


ID
:
    [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*
;

ASTERISK:'*';

WS
:
    [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
; 


grammar CronPartValidator;

options
   {
    tokenVocab = CronPartLexer;
}

cron_part
:
    minutes hours days_of_month month week_days time_zone?;

    minutes
:
    with_step_value
;


time_zone
:
    timezone_part
    (
        SLASH timezone_part
    )?
;

timezone_part
:
    ID
    (
        UNDERSCORE ID
    )?
;


hours
:
    with_step_value
;
//

//

days_of_month
:
    with_step_value
;
//

month
:
    with_step_value
;
//

week_days
:
    with_step_value
;


with_step_value:
    INT_LIST|ASTERISK|INTERVAL ((SLASH INT_LIST)?)  
;
```

[Parse Tree of the full string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMWE1.jpg)

[Parse Tree of "with_step_value" "*/3,5"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQSiY.jpg)

Comment: The `cron_part` rule is invalid and there is no `minute` rule defined. Also, the two images are actually the same. Make sure the posted grammar actually reproduces the problem reported.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "minutes" rule. I have it in the grammar

Answer (score 0):

The rule

```
with_step_value: INT_LIST|ASTERISK|INTERVAL ((SLASH INT_LIST)?) ;
```

will only match an `INT_LIST` or an `ASTERISK` or an `INTERVAL (SLASH INT_LIST)?`.

Perhaps this is what was intended:

```
with_step_value
    : ( INT_LIST
      | ASTERISK
      | INTERVAL
      ) (SLASH INT_LIST)?
    ;
```

[image]